# Is any answer added to a Community Wiki question automatically converted to a Community Wiki answer?

Tags: discussion, support, questions, answers, community-wiki

Is any answer added to a Community Wiki question automatically converted to a Community Wiki answer? Or does the answer stay 'a normal answer' as long as the answerer did not perform a specific action?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [What are “Community Wiki” posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740/310998) on Meta Stack Exchange:

> An answer posted to a community wiki question will also be community wiki.

So yes, if a question is Community Wiki, all answers are automatically Community Wiki too.